# Raw Printing - StartDocPrinterW

Tags: c#, winapi, printing

I call Native Methods for raw printing.

```
if (NativeMethods.OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
{
    if (NativeMethods.StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, ref di)) //My problem is here
    {
        if (NativeMethods.StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
        {
            bSuccess = NativeMethods.WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
            NativeMethods.EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        NativeMethods.EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
    }
    NativeMethods.ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
}
```

Everything is working. But when i call the line with "//My problem is here" my default printer get changed to that printer?

How do i keep the current default printer?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a null pointer for the printer name the default printer will be used.

Comment: Sorry but thats not what i've asked. The problem is i want to print to the specified printer (multiple queues). But when i call the function to print there, the printer i've specified gets the default printer. I don't want to use the default printer.